# Is series $\ln\frac{n+1}{n-1}$ converging?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

We already know that

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} x \ln \frac{x+1}{x-1} = 2$$

(this could be easily proved using L’Hospital’s rule.)

Then, how could we conclude (based on the limit provided) that the series

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \ln\frac{n+1}{n-1} $$

converges or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that $$\ln x>\dfrac{x-1}{x}\ \ \ \ \ \ \forall x>0,x\ne1$$
$$\implies\sum_{n=2}^\infty\ln\dfrac{n+1}{n-1}>\sum_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{2}{n+1}=\infty$$

**Edit**

Proof of first inequality:

Define function
$$f(x)=\ln x-\dfrac{x-1}{x}$$
$$\implies f'(x)=\dfrac{x-1}{x^2}$$
Therefore, by first derivative test, $f$ takes its minimum value at $x=1$ (verify!), which is $0$.

Comment: I upvoted, but if the original question is what needs to be proved, then I am sure your first inequality would need to be proved, too.

Comment: @DerekLuna, I expect OP to know it (or be able to do it, it's easy). I'll include the proof if he asks in the comments.

Comment: @Martund Could you provide a proof for the first inequality, as you stated in your comment?

Comment: @Jigsaw, I have provided the proof.

Answer (score 4):

You know that $\ln \frac{n+1}{n-1}\sim \frac2n$ as $n\to\infty$, and that $\sum\frac2n$ diverges.  By the limit comparison test, so does $\sum\ln \frac{n+1}{n-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

$\sum_\limits{n=2}^N \ln \frac {n+1}{n-1}\\
\sum_\limits{n=2}^N \ln  (n+1) - \ln (n-1)\\
\ln N + \ln (N+1) - \ln 2$

As $N$ approaches infinity $\ln N + \ln (N+1) - \ln 2$ also goes toward infinity.